# AS3 YouTube chromeless player ads affect the parent application scale property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, youtube, chromeless

### *Summary*

I have a Youtube API chromeless player in my Flex/AS3 application. 
All worked fine until last month we started to experience a zoom-in problem on page reloading.

### *Problem description*

Here is the example of **normal** state of the application playing YouTube video:

[image: YouTube chromeless player inside the application: normal state]

After reloading the web page:
[image: YouTube chromeless player inside the application: problematic state]

### *Problem's pre-conditions*

This happens only on some ads, and once it happened it will be easily reproducible again and again until this Ad is changed by something else. I'm not sure what Ad is causing the problem and not 100% sure that it is an Ad who causes the problem, but almost 99% it is it.

### *Question*

Has somebody experienced the same problem? Or how can I enforce the Google Ads not to affect the main application in anyway without getting Sandbox violation exceptions?

### *P.S.*

Unfortunately it's very complicated to provide the source code of the application, but YoutTube player implementation is fully according to the google's examples, and worked on production for a long time already.

Comment: Seems like the **allowscriptaccess='always'** should be exchanged by the **allowscriptaccess='sameDomain'** when loading the SWF inside the html page.

Comment: I think its because of the Ad Video dimensions (height and width). And we don't have command over the internal video size change control over the youtube video player. But we can try to find out internal property and video  component. After getting Video component, apply resize dimensions of video component.

Comment: It may be simpler to provide the necessary code by means of a screenshot.